Quantum algorithm for finding minimum $x$ such that $f(x)=1$
I am currently working on a project which includes the comparison of strings in $O(\sqrt{n})$ complexity where $n$ is the length of the string.  The reference for this algorithm can be found in Khadiev, K., & Enikeeva, S. (2022). Quantum version of self-balanced binary search tree with strings as keys and applications. International Conference on Micro- and Nano-Electronics 2021. The exact part of the algorithm that I cannot find the algorithm for is the following:
Given a blackbox function $f: \{1,\dots, N\} \to \{0, 1\}$ for some integer $N$. Find the minimum value of $x$ such that $f(x) = 1$. The algorithm mentioned in the paper above does this in constant bounded error probabilty and $O(\sqrt{N})$ query complexity.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For any $i\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$ set
\begin{align}
T[i] = \begin{cases}
i & \textrm{if }f(i)=1 \\
i+N & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and use Dürr's and Høyer's quantum algorithm for finding the minimum. That algorithm finds $i$ such that $T[i]$ is minimum. It makes $O\left(\sqrt{N}\right)$ calls to the oracle for $T$. The oracle for $T$ makes a single call to the oracle for $f$, so the overall algorithm has the desired query complexity.
The error probability of the algorithm is at most $\frac12$ and becomes at most $\frac{1}{2^c}$ if we run it $c$ times, so it satisfies the constant bounded error probability requirement, too.

Do you know if there is a readily available implementation of the algorithm in qiskit?

Nope, sorry, I don't know.
